# Using IDistributedCache and Redis in ASP.NET 5/MVC 6 - type or namespace 'Microsoft.Caching' does not exist

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am experimenting with the utilization of Redis cache in MVC 6 but I can't get my project to build.

I followed the examples at https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/tree/dev/samples - there is an IDistributedCache sample and a Redis sample.  However, it's not entirely clear because the Redis sample isn't a web app.

I have this in my project.json dependencies:

```
    "Microsoft.Framework.Cache.Memory": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Caching.Distributed": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Caching.Redis": "1.0.0-*",
```

I used this to get my packages:

> kpm install Microsoft.Framework.Caching.Distributed

and

> kpm install Microsoft.Framework.Caching.Redis

Both commands worked and returned an OK.

And in my startup I'm trying the following:

```
 services.AddSingleton<IMemoryCache, MemoryCache>();
 services.AddSingleton<IDistributedCache, RedisCache>();
```

When trying to build or run, the error given is:

> Startup.cs(10,27): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Caching'
>   does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Framework' (are you missing
>   an assembly reference?) Startup.cs(11,27): error CS0234: The type or
>   namespace name 'Caching' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Microsoft.Framework' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   Startup.cs(25,35): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   'IDistributedCache' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?) Startup.cs(25,54): error CS0246:
>   The type or namespace name 'RedisCache' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Now obviously I have the wrong references - but what are the right references?  I'm copying the namespaces directly from the samples?  I tried switching to Microsoft.Cache.Distributed and that didn't work either (and conflicted with github)

I have a feeling this is to do with not having the correct K version and maybe that's the way out - upgrading to the latest version.  There is a mismatch between Framework.Cache.Memory and Framework.Cache.Distributed and I see github comments relating to namespace changes.

If anyone can point the way out of this maze, much appreciated.

Comment: try beta4 instead beta3

Comment: beta4 specifically where - for the whole project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The below answer applies for **1.0.0-beta4** release of caching library which corresponds to here: https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/tree/1.0.0-beta4

[`IMemoryCache`](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/1.0.0-beta4/src/Microsoft.Framework.Caching.Interfaces/IMemoryCache.cs) is under `Microsoft.Framework.Caching.Memory` namespace and [`IDistributedCache`](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/1.0.0-beta4/src/Microsoft.Framework.Caching.Distributed/IDistributedCache.cs) is under `Microsoft.Framework.Caching.Distributed` namespace.

Dependencies would look like this:

```
"dependencies": { 
    "Microsoft.Framework.Caching.Memory": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Caching.Distributed": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Caching.Redis": "1.0.0-beta4"
}
```

So, `Microsoft.Framework.Cache.Memory` is `Microsoft.Framework.Caching.Memory`.

Comment: The issue is that those namespaces are not resolving.  If you see my project.json references, I have those in (they are also stated as 'using' statements in the startup.cs file).

Comment: I have tried this but unfortunately hosed my entire install.  Also tried going from KRE to DNX and failed at that as well.  Jumping from beta3 to beta4 has been fatal. I'll have to work through it and come back when I clear the decks and get what I had running again.

Comment: Ok this works I finally got it going.  A question though - is there any other Distributed caching implementations except for Redis?